# Why am i getting an OptimisticLockException?

Tags: java, jpa, openjpa

i'm trying to update an entity list. Actually i have to update each entity twice. First i need to set some state, then perform some operations for generating a pdf report, then update that entity's state again. And i'm getting this OptimisticLockException. This table is not being updated anywhere else in the system. I don't know what am i doing wrong.

```
public void procesarImpresiones() {
    Query q = em.createNamedQuery("Gapendte.selectByState");


    for (Object p:q.getResultList()){
        Gapendte pend = (Gapendte) em.merge(p);

        pend.setKy1("2");

        em.flush();

        try{

            //print something to pdf
            ...

            pend.setKy1("9");
        }catch (Exception e) {
            pend.setKy1("7");
        }

        em.flush();
    }    
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The flush is updating the entity version in the database.  i would think the new version number would be reloaded into the current instance, but it seems like it isn't.  you should try calling `em.refresh(pend)` after the flush.

Comment: No, unfortunately that didn't do the trick. Throws the same exception.

Comment: @HoracioGonzález - are you using explicit version numbers on your entities?  if so, have you investigated what the values are in the db and in memory, and when they change?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using connection pools and that stuff, you'll gonna need to reconfigure the locks or at least their times. From the JBoos docs:
"Transactional isolation is usually implemented by locking whatever is accessed in a transaction. There are two different approaches to transactional locking: Pessimistic locking and optimistic locking.

The disadvantage of pessimistic locking is that a resource is locked from the time it is first accessed in a transaction until the transaction is finished...
...With optimistic locking, a resource is not actually locked when it is first is accessed by a transaction. Instead, the state of the resource at the time when it would have been locked with the pessimistic locking approach is saved..."

So you have to configure the right lock strategy and time, something like:

```
    EntityManager em = ...;
    Person person = ...;
    em.lock(person, LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC);
```

Taken from java EE 6 documents http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkjiu.html

Answer (score 0):

Even tough i don't have a solution i know for sure that the question is misguided. The error is generated because of some wierd encoding incompatibility. It has nothing to do with locks (at least not directly) but with certain data stored in the @id fields i'm trying to update.